# Using Match and Address functions within Macro or VBA

Tags: excel, excel-match, vba

I have two worksheets, I want to use a value in sheet `to_approve` to lookup against `column A` in sheet `submitted`, then identify the cell reference so I can paste a value in the cell adjacent (`column B`).

I have used the following to identify the cell reference, but I don't know how to use it in VBA code.

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(To_Approve!D19,Submitted!A:A,0),1,4,1,"submitted")
```

Answer (score 2):

While many functions can be used in VBA using `Application.WorksheetFunction.FunctionName` ADDRESS is not one of these (MATCH is)

But even it it was available I would still use a **Find method** as below as it:

- gives you the ability to match whole or part strings, case sensitive or not
- returns a range object to work with if the value is found
- readily handles a no match
- you can control the point in the range being search as to where the search starts
- multiple matches can be returned with `FindNext`

something like

```
Sub GetCell()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("submitted")
    Set rng1 = ws.Columns("A").Find(Sheets("To_Approve").[d19], , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox rng1.Address & " in sheet " & ws.Name
    Else
        MsgBox "not found", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That is excellent, how do I use rng1 as the basis of a select

Comment: `Application.Goto rng1` in place of `MsgBox rng1.Address & " in sheet " & ws.Name`. cheers Dave

Answer (score 0):

This example should give you an idea of how to find a corresponding value on another sheet and place a second value in the the column to the left. When using VBA, it is not necessary to select cells and then paste; you can directly enter a value into a range (cell) object.

```
Sub TransferValue()
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Dim dValue As Double
    ' initialization
    Set rngSearch = Worksheets("to_approve").Range("D19")
    dValue = Date
    ' find the match & insert value
    Set rngFind = Worksheets("submitted").Columns(1).Find(What:=rngSearch.Value)
    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        rngFind.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = dValue
    End If
End Sub
```

(Note: dValue is a placeholder for whatever value you want to enter.)