# How to use address function which has two match functions as inputs into macro or VBA?

Tags: excel, match, vba

I currently have a formula which reads:

```
ADDRESS(MATCH(Schedule!A2,Wins!$A$1:$A$33,0),MATCH(Schedule!C2,Wins!$A$1:$AG$1,0))
```

I want to be able to use the cell reference returned in a macro for other calculations. I am new to Macros and was confused by some of the code in similar questions. I would like to use the returned reference in a calculation such as.

```
Worksheets("Record").Range("**").Value = Worksheets("Record").Range("**") - 1
```

In the similar question asked in link below seems to return the value in a message box. I won't have the errors listed in the post as I will always be matching the entire cell contents, which will always match a value in the reference vectors and never be empty. The other thing is I don't understand the `xlValues, xlWhole` is for. Here is the code from that post.

```
Sub GetCell()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Set ws = Sheets("submitted")
   Set rng1 = ws.Columns("A").Find(Sheets("To_Approve").[d19], , xlValues, xlWhole)
   If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox rng1.Address & " in sheet " & ws.Name
   Else
    MsgBox "not found", vbCritical
   End If
End Sub
```

I also tried:

```
Worksheets("Wins").Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(A1*,A1:A33,0),
    WorksheetFunction.Match(C1*,A1:A33,0).Address
```

The problem I had is that the `A1*` and `C1*` need to come from sheet `schedule` while the `A1:A33` need to come from Sheet `Wins`. Also it would not take the range `A1:A33` because of the ":"

[Using Match and Address functions within Macro or VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398930/excel-using-match-and-address-functions-within-macro-or-vba)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the address or match function but if you're trying to match cells and want to do it in vba, just use vba for everything?

Comment: I am trying to do it all in VBA. The function listed at the top gets the output I want, but the address function can't be used in VBA. The Address function returns the cell reference. If I have Column headers A,B,C,D and Rows Adam,Bob,Carl,Dan. I use the match and address function to return the cell reference, of (Bob, D) as (E2)

Comment: Shouldn't (Bob,D) be D2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
Dim strTmp1$, strTmp2$, strAddress$
Dim rngTmp1 As Range, rngTmp2 As Range

strTmp1 = Worksheets("Schedule").Range("A2").Value
strTmp2 = Worksheets("Schedule").Range("C2").Value

Set rngTmp1 = Worksheets("Wins").Range("A1:A33") _
    .Find(What:=strTmp1, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set rngTmp2 = Worksheets("Wins").Range("A1:AG1") _
    .Find(What:=strTmp2, LookAt:=xlWhole)

strAddress = Intersect(rngTmp1.EntireRow, _
    rngTmp2.EntireColumn).Address

With Worksheets("Record").Range(strAddress)
    .Value = .Value - 1
End With
```

As far as your question about xlValues, xlWhole, refer to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Note especially: The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried:
>
> Worksheets("Wins").Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(A1*,A1:A33,0),
>       WorksheetFunction.Match(C1*,A1:A33,0).Address
>
> but...

you can replace

A1* by `Worksheets("schedule").range("A1")`

C1* by `Worksheets("schedule").range("C1")`

A1:A33 by `Worksheets("Wins").range("A1:A33")`